# java -version display 1.7 when java is 1.6

Tags: java

This question is not joke or something like this. I have two jdk on my machine
JAVA_HOME points to jdk1.6, in PATH there is jdk1.6/bin

How this could be:

```
C:\Users\anteastra>where java
C:\Windows\System32\java.exe
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_33\bin\java.exe

C:\Users\anteastra>java -version
java version "1.7.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_05-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.1-b03, mixed mode)

C:\Users\anteastra>
```

It`s only one java/bin in PATH, where is no user variable PATH.

*addition to question.*
I moved path to java.exe in front of variable PATH, and java version number become the correct as should

```
C:\Users\anteastra>java -version
java version "1.6.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_45-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.45-b01, mixed mode)
C:\Users\anteastra>where java
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_33\bin\java.exe
C:\Windows\System32\java.exe

C:\Users\anteastra>echo %PATH%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_33\bin;C:\app\anteastra\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\b
in;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;C:\Program Files\Common File
s\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Sh
ared\Windows Live;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\win
dows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio
Shared\DLLShared\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\OEM\DLLShared
\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\OEM\DLLShared\;c:\Program Fil
es (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\OEM\12.0\DLLShared\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Ro
xio\OEM\AudioCore\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\P
ostgreSQL\9.1\bin;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin;C:\Program Files\T
ortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.8.4\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGi
t\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\maven3\bin;C:\Program File
s\nodejs\;C:\App\TortoiseHg\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap

C:\Users\anteastra>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_33
```

Anyway, thanks for hacks ;) looks like there are java.exe in some folder in path, but 'where' search somehow different from windows.

OH, i didn`t notice there are TWO java.exe from 'where' thx to all ))

Comment: What does `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_33\bin\java.exe" -version` show? (note that there are *two* results from `where`)

Comment: Do `echo %PATH%` and paste it in the question, do you have two entries?  Did you remember to close and open the command prompt when you added it to the path?

Comment: Can you paste the content of PATH variable and JAVA_HOME variable?

Comment: Try to rename `C:\Windows\System32\java.exe` to `java.exe.bak` and relaunch `java -version`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have more than one entry to Java in your PATH. You can check it out by using "echo %PATH%" which will print all the content of environment variable PATH. FYI, the command "where" search for the argument in the PATH, which may differ from which is the first location where windows can find java.exe. Also, remember you (or some installer) could create an shortcut to java.exe (or sth like it) somewhere you doesn't expect (in this case, I would recommend to search for java.exe files in your computer).GL